# Add a button in MySQL results using PHP

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

```
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $rows[] = $row;
}
$colNames = array_keys(reset($rows));

echo "<thead>";
echo "<tr>";
foreach ($colNames as $colName) {

    echo "<th>$colName</th>";

}
echo "<th>SEND EMAIL</th>";
echo "</tr>";
echo "</thead>";

echo "<tbody >";
echo "<tr>";
foreach ($rows as $row) {
    foreach ($colNames as $colName) {

        echo "<td>" . $row[$colName] . "</td>";

    }
    echo "<td><a href='Email.php?StudentID=???' class='btn btn-default left-margin'>Email</a></td>";
    echo "</tr>";
}

echo "</tbody>";
```

I am trying to add a button to each of the rows, So when a user clicks the button the correct ID is sent by POST. The column Name that the id resides is called StudentID

Comment: `echo "<td><a href='Email.php?StudentID=".$row['id']."' class ...`

Comment: The ID is not being sent, all I get is "Email.php?StudentID=" if I look at the source I can see the ID is being pulled but just not being sent by post

Comment: your link will require `$_GET`, not `$_POST`

Comment: [Understanding Get and Post](http://www.phpknowhow.com/get-and-post/understanding-get-and-post/)

Comment: Thank you the $_GET worked and also I had to rearrange the single quotes
'echo "<td><a href=Email.php?StudentID=".$row['StudentID']." class='btn btn-default left-margin'>Email</a></td>";'

Comment: @Sean You should add it as an answer as it solve the OP's problem. :)